# ant if target failing

Tags: java, ant, ant-contrib

I have an ant task which reads environment property from
`myproject.properties`. The environment property value is set to
`prod` and am displaying that "Prod condition is true". I see that
`${environment}` variable is set to prod, but if condition is never true. Can
someone explain why?

myproject.properties:

```
environment=prod
```

build.xml:

```
<project name="my-project" default="run" basedir=".">
  <property file="myproject.properties" />
  <target name="run">
  <echo message="running target run ${environment}"/>
    <if>
      <equals arg1="${environment}" arg2="prod">
        <then>
          <echo message="Prod condition is true"/>
           <!--do prod environment specific task-->
       </then> 
    </if>    
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Please correct this build script, as Isaac suggested. Try to run the exact script you publish, to avoid confusion and reproduction problems.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the fact that your `equals` task is missing an end-tag (it should be a self-closing tag, actually), I'm willing to bet that you have a whitespace hiding somewhere. In your `echo`, surround the printout of the property with apostrophes or something:

`<echo message="running target run '${environment}'"/>`

And you might see a whitespace at the end of the value. That's the only reasonable explanation I can think of. Alternatively, try running with `-Denvironment=prod` and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution uses core ANT. It avoids using the "if" task provided by the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) extension.

```
<project name="my-project" default="run" basedir=".">
    <property file="myproject.properties" />

    <condition property="prod.set">
        <equals arg1="${environment}" arg2="prod"/>
    </condition>

    <target name="run" if="prod.set">
        <echo message="Prod condition is true"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you would have had done this, but just to remind, did you include antcontrib jar and placed related taskdef in your project.xml ? if not, please correct the build file, and copy ant contrib jar in to the classpath

```
<project name="SampleWS" default="run" basedir=".">
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" classpath="lib/ant-contrib-0.6.jar" onerror="ignore"/>
 <property file="myproject.properties" />
 <target name="run">
 <echo message="running target run ${environment}"/>
    <if>
      <equals arg1="${environment}" arg2="prod"/>
        <then>
          <echo message="Prod condition is true"/>
           <!--do prod environment specific task-->
       </then> 
   </if>    
</target>
</project>
```